# run the same hosts on my local network?

Tags: router, webserver, localhost

I don't know how to explain that but I want to do the same like if I got in my hosts file any host to resolve but in a network scope. when the try to access to some website like `http:///www.google.co.uk/` they redirect to my local web server.

Comment: Do you mean that for any device on your network, if someone tries to go to google.com, they instead go to your webserver?  Would this be for all sites, or just a few?

Answer (score 0):

In your router you will have a route like this: destination 0.0.0.0 gateway 192.169.0.1 (your network may be different). Change the destination address to the local webserver you want your traffic to point at.  Keep in mind this change will keep any traffic from leaving your local network, effectively cutting internet access to your network.  This may or may not be possible on your router depending on how advanced it is.  In the end you are changing your routers default route.